# How does one INSERT from SELECT a JSON into MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

*[edit]*.
**It is working.** Seems like I was swinging between json_value & json_extract for extraction, and query caching was showing me wrong results. It is surely working with json_extract. Dropping table, creating new one with json_extract worked.
I have a table with JSON data.

```
create table a1 (
  data mediumtext null
)
```

I have few rows in it as such -

```
insert into a1 (data) values ('{"key1": "something", "key2": {"this": "is", "nested": "json"}}')
```

I have a new table -

```
create table a2 (
 key2 mediumtext null
)
```

I am trying move the `key2` data into a2's new column.

```
insert into a2 (new_column)
select json_extract(data, '$.key2') as key2
from a1;
```

Select part alone seems to be working.
But JSON isn't being copied. It is coming as null. What seems to be wrong here?

Comment: Can you share schema and samples from table `a2` too?

Comment: @lemon, edited to reflect `a2` structure.

Comment: I tested this on MySQL 8.0, and it works fine. Please create a dbfiddle to demonstrate it not working.

Comment: Apologies. Seems like I was swinging between json_value & json_extract and seems like query caching was showing me wrong results. It is surely working with json_extract.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not recognize `new_column` as a valid column for the table `a2`.

You should change your `INSERT` operation as done followingly:

```
insert into a2 (key2)
select json_extract(data, '$.key2') as key2
from a1;
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wuh9mqy2WChafTSJfdEjYL/0).

Comment: Tried this. Still no go. BTW, non-JSON types are being copied fine. Like key1 will be copied fine if I try. key2 being nested JSON doesn't work.

Comment: are there differences between the fiddle and your code?

Comment: It is working. I was using mariadb json_value instead of extract. It is not same. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: If this check helped you, that was no wasted time, no worries man.